# how to disable a button outside my update panel?

Tags: gridview, updatepanel

I have a dotnet 2.0 web application.

And there is a button outside my update panel...

Inside update panel..i have a gridview ...While sorting grid, i need to disable the button outside the update panel.

Please help me.

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td>
  <UpdatePanel>
       <gridview />
  </UpdatePanel>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
 <Button />
 </td>
</tr>
<table>
```

EDIT:

I tried the below code on server side sorting function - but not working

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "",
                        "<script>document.getElementById('" + ((Button)DualGridTableRow.FindControl(string.Concat(WebConstants.PriorityText, WebConstants.UpText))).ClientID + "').style.enabled ='False';</script>"
                        , true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add disable functionality in the onclick event of your sort buttons(links). Don't know if it is elegant, however it will work.
Just one point, if you need it just for disabling button while async sort I think it is unnecessary.